# styled-components in nextjs

Tags: next.js, styled-components, css-in-js

I did config styled-components in my nextjs projects sometimes the style it works  and sometimes when i refresh the page it doesn't work how to fix this ?

```
/* registry.jsx */

'use client';

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useServerInsertedHTML } from 'next/navigation';
import { ServerStyleSheet, StyleSheetManager } from 'styled-components';

export default function StyledComponentsRegistry({
  children,
}) {
  const [styledComponentsStyleSheet] = useState(() => new ServerStyleSheet());

  useServerInsertedHTML(() => {
    const styles = styledComponentsStyleSheet.getStyleElement();
    styledComponentsStyleSheet.instance.clearTag();
    return <>{styles}</>;
  });

  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') return <>{children}</>;

  return (
    <StyleSheetManager sheet={styledComponentsStyleSheet.instance}>
      {children}
    </StyleSheetManager>
  );
}     


/* document.js */

import { Head, Html, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import StyledComponentsRegistry from "../../libs/registry";

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head />`your text`
      <StyledComponentsRegistry>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </StyledComponentsRegistry>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

this is the code that i have configured what i'm missing ?